# Take the "Head" of every file in a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, python-3.x

I am working with large files, and my question here is two-fold.

1. **Bash** - For testing purposes, I would like to iterate over every file in a given directory, taking the `Head` of each file (say `Head
   10000`), and be left with a cut-down version of each. Either in the
   same directory or another it doesn't matter a whole lot, though I
   suppose the same would be preferred.
2. **Python3** - How can I do this programmatically? I imagine I need to use the **[os module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os)**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this using [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
for i in *; do
    cp "$i" "$i.tail"
    sed -i '10001,$d' "$i.tail"
done
```

or simply :

```
for i in *; do
    sed '10001,$d' "$i" > "$i.tail"
done
```

or :

```
for i in *; do
    head -n 1000 "$i" > "$i.tail"
done
```

For python, see http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html if you would like to use the shell code.

Comment: Nice, the bash part works. Had to change `cp "$1 "$i.tail"` to `cp "$1" "i.tail"`

Comment: I did not want a link to `python` documentation, as I know where `python` docs are located. I was looking for a Python solution for the problem. Your bash works, but no python. `Wing Tang`'s Python works, but not his bash solution. I wish I could give 50% to each, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

**Bash:**

The most straightforward way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
DEST=/tmp/
for i in *
do
   head -1000 "${i}" > ${DEST}/${i}
done
```

If you have a large number of files, you can run multiple jobs by generating a list of files, splitting them out, and running the loop against each list.

**Python:**

Assuming the goal is to not spawn shell sessions to execute external binaries, like 'head', this is how I would go about it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os

destination="/tmp/"

for file in os.listdir('.'):
  if os.path.isfile( file ):
    readFileHandle = open(file, "r")
    writeFileHandle = open( destination + file , "w")
    for line in range( 0,1000):
      writeFileHandle.write(readFileHandle.readline())
    writeFileHandle.close()
    readFileHandle.close()
```

Comment: I thought this would work for me, but after running the script I am left with files of size 0..? Some are `.gz` files, so I can see why I may need to decompress them first. But others in the directory are just `.tsv`, `.txt`, etc.

Comment: It is the bash script I am talking about.

Comment: Hmm... it's generating the correct filenames, but they are zero length? That's quite odd.

Even a .gz file would have resulted in an output file >0 bytes, albeit corrupted.

Are you able to "cat" a file from the source to the destination folder?

Comment: Just realized, "head -1000" may behave differently on your system vs mine, as I realized the answer you flagged as an answer uses "head" differently. In either case, glad you got workable answers.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Well, in any case, I got the results I needed and thank you very much for your help Wing.

Comment: Yeah, no prob. Was fun to write out the Python version. :)

Answer (score -1):

To abbreviate all files in the current dir in this way, you can use:

```
for f in *; do [[ $f != *.small ]] && head -n 10000 "$f" > "$f".small; done
```

The files will be suffixed with `.small`.

To do this from python,

```
import os
os.system('for f in *; do [[ $f != *.small ]] && head -n 10000 "$f" > "$f".small; done')
```

Comment: `os.system()` is deprecated in 2013. Use `subprocess` instead